# Help with making a simple rectangular page border

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I add a plain rectangle page border offset by 1.5 cm from the edge of the page?  I'd prefer to use \TikZ if possible.

Comment: On all pages? Should this boarder be the same as the available text space?

Comment: All pages, unrelated to available text space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)$)--($(current page.north west)+(1.5cm,-1.5cm)$)--($(current page.south west)+(1.5cm,1.5cm)$)--($(current page.south east)+(-1.5cm,1.5cm)$)--cycle;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Set the border in all pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\myborder}{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)$)--($(current page.north west)+(1.5cm,-1.5cm)$)--($(current page.south west)+(1.5cm,1.5cm)$)--($(current page.south east)+(-1.5cm,1.5cm)$)--cycle;}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\myborder}
\begin{document}
content
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is it, thanks!  I see how that works but I didn't know the syntax.

Comment: you're welcome :) I'm sure you'll improve this code

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\cornersize{0}
\fancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.5)}%
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP is asking for something different.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a hammersledge to obtain this frame on every page: `eso-pic` and simple `\framebox` and `\raisebox` commands with the relevant parameters will do the trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt,svgnames, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\dimdef{\frameheight}{\dimexpr\paperheight-3cm-\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\dimdef{\framewidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}

\title{Page Frames}
\author{My Self}

\date{}
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{%
\fboxrule = 1pt
\hspace*{1.5cm}\raisebox{1.5cm}{\color{DarkSeaGreen}\framebox[\framewidth]{\rule{0pt}{\frameheight}}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One package and one line of code was sufficient for me:
`\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\hspace*{2cm}\raisebox{3.1cm}{\framebox[17cm]{\rule{0pt}{24cm}}}}`